# Create File Browser

Tags: eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, emf

I am trying to create a file browser when the user clicks on a button at the property I have generated.
The following code I use,it fetches the whole files at my workspace.
However,I need to browse over all my PC.

```
IFile[] files = WorkspaceResourceDialog.openFileSelection(null, "File selection", "Please select any file", false, null, null);
```

Any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

```
      ResourceDialog resourceDialog=
     new ResourceDialog(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell(), 
"Select your image", SWT.OPEN);

        resourceDialog.create();
        resourceDialog.open();
        String path=resourceDialog.getURIText();
```